# Parenthesis in Domain

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, notation

I just had a quick question about a notation I saw.  I know that a $C^2$  function is a function whose second partial derivative exists. But, what does it mean when one writes $C^2(U)$ where $U$ is a subset of $R^n$? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that $f$ is $C^2$ **on** $U$. It is just to specify to a domain on which we have the $C^2$ property.

If $U$ happens to be non-open, then it means that there exists $\widetilde{U}$ an open neighborhood of $U$ and $F\in C^2(\widetilde{U})$ such that $F_{\vert U}=f$.

Comment: What is that notation with the |U you used there?

Comment: You definitely hate notation, just joking! (: It stands for the restriction of $F$ at $U$.